# How do I truncate a value to so I can compare to another?

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress and learning the ropes. In my test I am trying to get two values, combine them and do a calculation on those to validate against. The code is mostly working, however this is a currency based test so if the results go beyond 2 decimal places the validation fails. I don't want to do any rounding, just truncate beyond the cent (example: 24.558 should be 24.55)

This is my code, I'm getting a sub total, adding in a shipping cost, multiplying it by a tax amount and validating that against the tax shown. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
cy.get('.sub-total')
   .invoke('text')
   .then(text => +text.replace('$','').trim())
   .then(initial => {
      cy.get('.shipping-total-cost')
      .invoke('text')
      .then(text => +text.replace('$','').trim())
      .then(secondary => {
         cy.get('.tax-total')
         .invoke('text')
         .then(text => +text.replace('$','').trim())
         .should('eq',(initial + secondary) * this.contactDetails.taxValue)
      })    
   })
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to store all the values as cents, truncate all calculations to integers, and only convert to dollars-and-cents at the display stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to `should('eq'...`, check for a maximum diff with a [closeTo](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_closeto) assertion.

```js
cy.get('.tax-total')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => +text.replace('$','').trim())
  .should('be.closeTo', (initial + secondary) * this.contactDetails.taxValue, 0.01)
```

---

Checking truncation, these all work

```js
expect(24.558).to.be.closeTo(24.55, 0.01)
expect(24.559).to.be.closeTo(24.55, 0.01)
expect(24.551).to.be.closeTo(24.55, 0.01)
```

but this doesn't

```js
expect(24.00).not.to.be.closeTo(23.999, 0.01)  // rounding up 23.999 -> 24.00
```

To truncate to 2 decimals, pre-format with a function

```js
const dec2 = (value) => {
  const text = value.toString()
  const match = text.match(/([0-9]*(\.?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)/)
  return +match[0]
}
```

```js
cy.get('.tax-total')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => +text.replace('$','').trim())
  .then(dec2)       // not needed if form validation restricts input to 2 decimals
  .should('be.closeTo', dec2((initial + secondary) * this.contactDetails.taxValue), 0.01)
```